# JQuery for Push-down form

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Is there a JQuery plugin that allows me to 'unhide' a form by after clicking a link? Like I have an invite link that can take me to a one text field form for an email address but I want this form to just drop down (pushing the rest of the content down also) and shows the form to submit the email. If you guys can think of a JQuery plugin that lets me do this, please let me know

Edit:
So I did this

```
<div class='add-link'>
        <div id='invite_link'><a href=''>Invite User</a></div>
        <div id='invitation_form'>
            <form>
                <input type='text'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my jquery looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
    { 
        $("table").tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[2,1]], widgets: ['zebra']}); 
                $('#invitation_form').hide();
    } 
);

$('#invite_link').click(function() {
    $('#invitation_form').slideDown();
});
```

Do you guys see any error that causes the form not to slide down. It hides the form when the page loads but when I click the link it is not sliding down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.mylink').click(function() {
    $('#MyForm').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `slideDown()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a jQuery plugin for this.  The base jQuery library should be sufficient.

```
$('#showFormLink').click(function () {
  $('#form').slideDown();
});
```

If you're looking for animation, that's possible as well by passing in a duration argument to slideDown.

Take a look at the jQuery [show documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).